# Oracle Sequence to change currval why not just drop it and recreate?

Tags: oracle, ddl

I want to increase the CURRVAL of a set of Sequences.

One option is to drop the Sequence and recreate it with a starting value equal to the value I want to increase to however I've come across a number of suggestions ([here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1999691), [here](https://gokhanatil.com/2011/01/how-to-set-current-value-of-a-sequence-without-droppingrecreating.html) and [here](http://ittichaicham.com/2011/05/change-sequences-current-value-currval-without-dropping-it/)) which don't drop it but instead :

- restrict access
- change the "increment by" to whatever value you with to increase CURRVAL by
- pull a value
- change "increment by" back to 1
- un-restrict access

This is all fine but I'm left wondering what's so bad about dropping the Sequence ?

I get it that the triggers will go invalid but the next time they're used they'll be recompiled - is this really such a big deal ?

Is there something I've overlooked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It becomes a big deal when there are lots of complex dependencies on either the sequence or between the trigger code and other pl/sql packages.

As a general practice, you want to minimize situations that will result in invalidated pl/sql code (stored procedures, packages, and trigger code). The auto compile will run on-demand the next time the code is called. But if you have a high volume transaction system or a large-scale application with complex dependencies, those delays (or subsequent exceptions) caused by recompiling may be unacceptable.

If your particular setup is such that the trigger code is very simple with no dependencies and you can perform the DDL during a time where the trigger will not be fired, it is probably acceptable to drop and recreate the synonym and then recompile the trigger code.